# volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use with torch.no_grad(): instead

Tags: pytorch, volatile

I have got this error, can you help me please?
This is my error in utils.py file

```
 content/gdrive/My Drive/DeepFakeDetection/utils.py:21: UserWarning:
 volatile was removed and now has no effect. Use with torch.no_grad():
 instead. return Variable(x, volatile=volatile)
```

And this is my code in utils.py file

```
 def to_var(x, volatile=False):
 
     if torch.cuda.is_available(): 
        x = x.cuda() 
     return Variable(x, volatile=volatile)
```

Thank you

Comment: Both `Variable` and `volatile` are deprecated and replaced with `torch.Tensor` and the context manager `torch.no_grad()`. In any case, it's just a warning and not an error, so you may choose to ignore it if the code is running correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to this:

```
def to_var(x, volatile=False):
>     
>     with torch.no_grad():
>         
>         if torch.cuda.is_available():
>             x = x.cuda()
>     return x
```